# How to use seaborn dotplot to represent multiple series on same graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use seaborn pairgrid/dotplot to represent the data in such a way that `2017_value`, `2020_value` and `2022_value` should come on the same graph.

This is how my sample dataframe looks like:

[image]

Code Snippet:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df,
                 x_vars=['growth','2017_value','2020_value','2022_value'], y_vars=["area"],
                 height=10, aspect=.50)

# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=10, orient="h", jitter=False,
      palette="flare_r", linewidth=1, edgecolor="w")


# Use the same x axis limits on all columns and add better labels
g.axes[0,0].set(xlim=(-1, 12.5), xlabel="", ylabel="")
g.axes[0,1].set(xlim=(0, 30), xlabel="", ylabel="")

for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.axvline(x=1,ls='--',linewidth=3,c='black')
# Use semantically meaningful titles for the columns
titles = ["Share", "Value1"]

for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, titles):

    # Set a different title for each axes
    ax.set(title=title)

    # Make the grid horizontal instead of vertical
    ax.xaxis.grid(False)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

Current Output: - Blue Dots represents the `2017_value`

[image]

Desired Output: - The red dots and black dots will be the `2020_value` and `2022_value`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 3 year data plotted together, you can use `pd.melt()` to melt the data for each of the years one below the other. Also, based on what the expected output picture looks like, I made some changes to color palette and remove the second axvline. Hope this is what you are looking for...

**My dummy data (before melt)**

```
>> df
    area    growth  2017_value  2020_value  2022_value
0   A   2   15  17  12
1   B   1   10  9   11
2   C   3   25  13  19
3   D   1   9   21  13
4   E   6   18  7   2
5   F   2   12  20  26
6   G   1   17  21  13
7   H   7   18  8   10
8   I   10  27  10  8
9   J   10  28  18  9
10  K   11  2   13  6
11  L   5   24  28  21
12  M   1   6   24  9
13  N   7   29  3   17
14  O   8   15  7   15
15  P   13  11  17  27
16  Q   9   13  1   7
17  R   9   23  1   19
18  S   13  1   3   10
19  T   0   6   30  26
20  U   0   22  1   27
21  V   6   10  28  24
22  W   13  15  1   5
23  X   7   28  21  1
24  Y   2   31  25  13
25  Z   3   7   4   8
```

**Updated code**

```
df=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['area', 'growth'], value_vars=['2017_value', '2020_value', '2022_value'])
#g = sns.PairGrid(df, x_vars=['growth','2017_value','2020_value','2022_value'], y_vars=["area"], height=10, aspect=.50)
g = sns.PairGrid(df, x_vars=['growth','value'], y_vars=["area"], hue="variable", height=10, aspect=.50)
# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=10, orient="h", jitter=False, linewidth=1, palette=['black', 'tab:orange', 'tab:blue'], edgecolor="w")
# Use the same x axis limits on all columns and add better labels
g.axes[0,0].set(xlim=(-1, 12.5), xlabel="", ylabel="")
g.axes[0,1].set(xlim=(0, 30), xlabel="", ylabel="")
#for ax in g.axes.ravel():
g.axes[0,0].axvline(x=1,ls='--',linewidth=3,c='black')
# Use semantically meaningful titles for the columns
titles = ["Share", "Value1"]
for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, titles):
    # Set a different title for each axes
    ax.set(title=title)
    # Make the grid horizontal instead of vertical
    ax.xaxis.grid(False)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
g.add_legend()
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Any method to change the order of A..Z  in the plot, I have numeric values in area column, and whatever sorting I'll do on df before passing its always displays it in ascending order.

Comment: If you need to sort in a specific order, then you would need to sort it the way you want it, then convert the column to strings (`as_type(str)`). That should work. If not, you will need to use `pd.Categorical()` and provide the order in which you want to sort the categorical values and sort it.... then plot it. Let me know if you need some info or, if still stuck, create another question on that.